# Conditional MySQL query - privacy of results

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I am trying to get the videos from a database table. The condition: the videos should only be included if the user's privacy setting does not restrict the viewing.

The video table:
[image: video table]

Privacy can be 0,1,2 or 3.

The relationship table:
[image: relationships]

Let's say I want to get a page of all videos, with the restriction that those videos of people that I am not friends with, should not be included. (Later on, I will have to extend this query to also include "contacts").

That means all videos that have this privacy setting should be queried:

privacy = 0

privacy != 1 (profile videos are hidden)

privacy = 3 **AND** I am on this members friends list

My userid is 1.

I tried this query, but it does not give me the desired result:

```
SELECT videos.*,
FROM `video_table` AS `videos`
WHERE 
(
    videos.privacy != 1
    OR (
        videos.privacy = 3
        AND '1' IN (
            SELECT friendslist.relationid
            FROM friendslist
            WHERE friendslist.userid = videos.userid
            AND friendslist.friend = 'yes'
        )
    )
)
LIMIT 20
```

I suppose the IF statement can only be used in the select part of the query?

The query in pseudo code:
SELECT all videos WHERE privacy != 1 AND IF (privacy = 3) { myuserid must be on users_friendslist} )

How can I show all videos but exclude the ones from people who I am not friends with?

Comment: How are the video and user tables related? Show the user table schema.

Comment: don't forget to accept an answer if it helped you, as a basic courtesy towards others...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM video_table AS v
WHERE privacy = 0
    OR (privacy = 3
        AND @myId IN (
            SELECT f.relationid
            FROM friendslist AS f
            WHERE f.userid = v.userid
            AND f.friend = 'yes'
        )
    )
LIMIT 20
```